# Print m values of dictionary c#

Tags: c#

```
public static void DoStuff()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int> {};
        Console.WriteLine("Enter m:");
        int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("m="+m);

      //  Console.WriteLine(enteredSurname+": "+ enteredCode);

        foreach (var p in pav)
        {
            int dif = 0;
            code=ChangeToCode(p);

            Console.WriteLine(p+": "+code);

            dif = CodeSimilarity(enteredSurname, p);
            myDict.Add(p, dif);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in myDict.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Value))
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I have sorted dictionary and I need to print m items of it. For example, if I enter m=2, I have to print two first items of dictionary. I tried adding k=0 and while( k< m) print those values but that doesn't seem to be a correct way, because it just prints dictionary m times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Take`, which is meant exactly for that:

```
foreach (var kvp in myDict.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Value).Take(m))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I I didn't know Take() before! Thaaank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to increment your k variable inside the loop and break out of the loop if m is reached.

```
int k = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in myDict.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Value))
{
    if (k>=m)
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    k++;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can do this in one step with `ìf (k++ >= m) break;` but I wanted to emphasise that there are two steps.
Or you just use `myDict.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Value).Take(m)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

K is number of prints

```
var kvp = myDict.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Value).ToList();    
for (int i=0;i<k;i++) 
{
 Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp[i].Key, kvp[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: I think you need at least `myDict.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Value).ToList();` - otherwise you can't access `kvp[i]`.